# I try to mount a created database from host, name mydb, onto mysql container here is what I’ve tried:

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-5.7

I try to mount a created database from host, name mydb, onto mysql container here is what I’ve tried:

sudo docker run -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/mydb/ --name mysql_web -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7

```
root@ip-172-31-16-134:/var/lib/mysql# sudo docker run -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql/mydb/ --name mysql_web -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7
3c0a8eb588c0dd0d0b7b72a727912744f44e744e700de7efc64a0c4c1f651685
root@ip-172-31-16-134:/var/lib/mysql# docker exec -it mysql_web bash
Error response from daemon: Container 3c0a8eb588c0dd0d0b7b72a727912744f44e744e700de7efc64a0c4c1f651685 is not running
```

but it works when I change where to mount…

sudo docker run -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mydb/ --name mysql_web -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7

```
root@ip-172-31-16-134:/var/lib/mysql# sudo docker run -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mydb/ --name mysql_web -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7
06233eeb864c32ff16d6542e632a4da3ff6dfbd4a30fcc9aac8086dfc1245948
root@ip-172-31-16-134:/var/lib/mysql# docker exec -it mysql_web bash
root@06233eeb864c:/# cd /var/lib/mydb
root@06233eeb864c:/var/lib/mydb# exit
exit
```

seems It can’t mount onto specific folder and I don’t know why, I just want both databases, one from host, and the other from container, synced itself instead of loading dump.sql everytime when I start a new container.

any suggestion would help , thanks

Comment: [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69) for the error you got `[ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.`

What this error means is explained [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69#issuecomment-98678411).

Try few things like

- Adding `--ignore-db-dir=lost+found` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69#issuecomment-365927214).
- Providing exact path of data directory on host and mount on to container path at `/var/lib/mysql` like this `docker run -v /path/to/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql --name mysql_web -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69#issuecomment-379567872).

Hope this helps.